# 'org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment' that could not be found

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Hi I am facing below issue while running springboot application (using springboot version 1.5.2). Appreciate your help.

Description:

Parameter 0 of method envInfoContributor in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.InfoContributorAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment' in your configuration.

Comment: did you find a solution to that?